# Issue displaying items in a GridView

Tags: java, android

I put a gridview in my app, and i display information. As you can see i have on top of each square the index number, starting to 0. When i scroll my screen, my numbers start to change after 17. The index start 0 again and go backwards

http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/8108/39248258.png

here is my code :

(onCreate function)

```
myGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
myGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

My BaseAdpater :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
   Context MyContext;

   public ImageAdapter(Context _MyContext)
   {
      MyContext = _MyContext;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() 
   {
                     /* Set the number of element we want on the grid */
      return searchResult.size();
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
   {
      View MyView = convertView;

      if ( convertView == null )
      {

         /*we define the view that will display on the grid*/

         //Inflate the layout
         LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
         MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

         String[] myData = searchResult.get(position);

         // Add The Text!!!
         TextView tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.no);
         tv.setText(" "+ position );

         TextView ap = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.apperture);
         ap.setText(" "+ myData[1] );

         TextView sp = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.speed);
         sp.setText(" "+ myData[2] );
      }

      return MyView;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return arg0;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return arg0;
   }
}
```

And item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/no" android:text="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/apperture"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/speed" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Have you ever seen this issue ? When i change of AVD (in a different resolution) the issue begin in a different index number
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is in getView. when you check if ( convertView == null ), you correctly don't reinflate a non-null view, but you fail to provide it with any new content

move

```
String[] myData = searchResult.get(position);

 // Add The Text!!!
 TextView tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.no);
 tv.setText(" "+ position );

 TextView ap = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.apperture);
 ap.setText(" "+ myData[1] );

 TextView sp = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.speed);
 sp.setText(" "+ myData[2] );
```

outside your if statement.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't realise how the reinflate view was working !

Comment: Listview recycles the item views, so that the expensive operation of reinflating from XML isn't performed unnecessarily. when a list item goes offscreen, its view may be passed into Adapter.getView as convertView, for reuse. As you now know, you need to provide new values in any case, or things get a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

in your `getView` method, you're only updating the values of the textViews if convertView is null. Android will pass an old view into getView via the convertView parameter in order to allow you to be more efficient (reusing already inflated views rather than creating a new one every time).